# Trouble with date ranges

Tags: mysql

I need to check for entries made in the last "x" days (example 30 days) and cannot get the query to work.  This is what I am using:

```
  SELECT   CAL_OWNER,
           CAL_TITLE,
           FROM_UNIXTIME (CAL_CREATED, "%m-%d-%y") AS CREATED,
           FROM_UNIXTIME (RANGE_START, "%Y-%m-%d") AS DATE2BESEEN,
           CASE CAL_REFERRAL_TYPE
              WHEN 1 THEN 'NoReferral'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'CareyGuide'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Education'
              WHEN 4 THEN 'Employment'
              WHEN 5 THEN 'Housing'
              WHEN 6 THEN 'Medical'
              ELSE 'NA'
           END
              AS REFERRALS
    FROM   EGW_CAL
   WHERE   CAL_CREATED BETWEEN (NOW () - '30 day') AND NOW ()
ORDER BY   REFERRALS ASC;
```

If I comment out the "WHERE range_start ... line the query runs fine, but pulls all data
However, if I run the complete query, it does not error, but there are no results (I have 4 entries in column cal_created in the last 3 weeks).

If some one can help I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using INTERVAL and either NOW() or CURDATE()..

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME (CAL_CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

curdate is just the date portion of the day

if you want to include the time use NOW()

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME (CAL_CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

you could also make a new date to use the between with

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME (CAL_CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

SOURCE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

**NOTE:** the dates need to be formatted correctly in order for it to work

---

FULL QUERY:

```
SELECT  
    CAL_OWNER,
    CAL_TITLE,
    FROM_UNIXTIME (CAL_CREATED, '%m-%d-%y') AS CREATED_AT,
    FROM_UNIXTIME (RANGE_START, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE2BESEEN,
    CASE CAL_REFERRAL_TYPE
        WHEN 1 THEN 'NoReferral'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'CareyGuide'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Education'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Employment'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Housing'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Medical'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS REFERRALS
FROM  EGW_CAL
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(CAL_CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
ORDER BY REFERRALS ASC;
```

Comment: When I use any of the 3 I get this it does not error, but results in MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0077 sec)

Comment: @Detox did you try CURDATE()?

Comment: @Detox not sure how NOW() is throwing an error... i added a reference in my answer. try using a different date format.. see my edited answer

Comment: yes, and it results in no data found  = MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0079 sec)

Comment: @Detox try using my full query it may have something to do with how you pull out cal_created as UNIX instead of just regular date_format

Comment: I tried all 3 again.  No errors, but no data found. That is the confusing part.  When I run the query without that line is shows all entries fine.  However, I'd hate to parse out un-needed data each time.  I appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57277/discussion-between-detox-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: @Detox I just edited again.. sorry i made a simple mistake on the query that should work

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and assistance

Answer (score 1):

- `CAL_CREATED` is a UNIX timestamp,
- `NOW()` will return a MySQL timestamp.

They don't mix automatically. So use

```
WHERE CAL_CREATED 
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

**Note:**

I wouldn't recommend to go the other way

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(CAL_CREATED) BETWEEN ...
```

because MySQL can't use an index in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `where` clause uses `internval`:

```
WHERE   CAL_CREATED BETWEEN NOW() - interval 30 day AND NOW()
```

The use of single quotes is reminiscent of Postgres.  In MySQL, it ends up treating the value of `now()` as an integer.  And it subtracts the string value "30 days" from it.

When `now()` is treated as an integer, it also has hours, minutes, and seconds.  So you are really subtracting something like 30 seconds.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is the documentation on `now()`.

Comment: The syntax defined by the SQL standard would be `interval '30' day` with only the actual value put in single quotes - I have never understood why the Postgres manual (still) prefers the non-standard syntax

Comment: @gordon   when I use 
WHERE cal_created BETWEEN NOW () - interval 30 day AND NOW ()
ORDER BY referrals ASC I get the following error:  #1630 - FUNCTION egwdata.NOW does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: First, there should be no space between `NOW` and the `()` (I accidentally left that in from your question).  Second, if you don't have the function `NOW()`, then you aren't using MySQL and you should retag the question.  (Or, better yet, ask a new question because this question already has answers which would likely be invalidated.)